Azure Blob Trigger | request body format
I tried to trigger the Azure blob function through ADF and got the following error.

I have an issue with the structure of the request body format. could you please explain the format of the request body?


json format needed.

Hi @wenbo,
{
"name": "Azure Function1",
"type": "AzureFunctionActivity",
"dependsOn": [],
"policy": {
"timeout": "0.12:00:00",
"retry": 0,
"retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
"secureOutput": false,
"secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
"functionName": "test",
"method": "POST"
},
"linkedServiceName": {
"referenceName": "AzureFunction1",
"type": "LinkedServiceReference"
}
}

The error says that blob trigger function cannot be called using ADF, The function only triggers when the blob gets uploaded and it is a behavior of the trigger.
Even In portal for Blob trigger:

If you have http trigger then you can call:

If you run Blob trigger from adf it fails as it cannot be called using get, post, put and all, function triggers only when new blob is added in specified container and path :

If you call http trigger it will succeeds as it is called by url/rest api:

Also refer this SO-thread.

Hi, Could you please explain how to run the Azure Blob trigger using ADF?

Blob Trigger Function is triggered whenever a Blob gets uploaded, or any modification and this trigger cannot be called from a external call like adf. If you want to call Http trigger then you can use ADF like above. Check this Doc on Blob Trigger.
